# Custom css in material-ui version4.9.0

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, classname

i have to update the material ui version in my project. The version i used was the 0.20 and now i've updated to v.4.9
I've changed all the imports from material-ui to @materia-ui/core and my app is compiling successfully. The issue i have is with the styling. I was not using styles in every component but i use a global css file which i import in my main.js and for each element and component i've add the style here. The problem is that the current material-ui components are styled wrong. For example the Chip component that i used i have a classname which is this:

```
.euro-chip-default {
    background-color: #FFF !important;
    border: 1px solid #E9EEF1 !important;
}
```

Now that i've updated the version this classname is now working properly. My chip is looking awefull. Is there anything i must do to use the css in the updated material ui project. From the docs i can't find a solution. They use the withStyles which i can't use since my components wil become huge
Thanks!

Comment: I use the global theming to theme my components globally, I create a theme object that overrides default styles and props, It can be really useful in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to update your css properties to match the ones they use here [Chip Styles](https://material-ui.com/api/chip/#css)

So in your styles.css file you could use

```
.MuiChip-root {
  background-color: #FFF !important;
  border: 1px solid #E9EEF1 !important;
}
```

And your chip would be styled as you want it

Like in here [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-bird-t9pb4)